How to annotate Agilent probeIDs and obtain corresponding RefSeqmRNA from NCBI in a microarray analysis in R?
I am working on a microarray analysis using Agilent data (SurePrint G3 Mouse GE 8x60K IDs e.g. A_30_P01020727), having the list of Probe IDs with it´s corresponding statistics and fold changes. My goal is obtain the corresponding RefSeqmRNA from NCBI to anotate them afterwards.
So far, I have tried different approaches combining several databases and internet searching tools without succes. I would like to know the best way to achieve this efficiently. I am open to using languages like R, and any suggestions on libraries or packages that can facilitate this process would be greatly appreciated.
Could you provide me with a guide or code examples to annotate Agilent identifiers and map them to RefSeqmRNA from NCBI?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
